# wildfly / jboss-eap: How to name JMS resources to match EJB2 ejb-jar.xml

Tags: java, jboss, ejb, wildfly, ejb-2.x

I currently migrate an EJB2 application to jboss-eap. The first phase tries to modify less source as possible.

The give `ejb-jar.xml` contains

```xml
<!DOCTYPE ejb-jar PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Enterprise JavaBeans 2.0//EN" "http://java.sun.com/dtd/ejb-jar_2_0.dtd">
<ejb-jar id="ejb-jar_ID">
      [...]
      <session >

         [...]

         <resource-ref >
            <res-ref-name>jms/customQueueFactory</res-ref-name>
            <res-type>javax.jms.QueueConnectionFactory</res-type>
            <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
            <res-sharing-scope>Shareable</res-sharing-scope>
         </resource-ref>

         <resource-env-ref >
            <resource-env-ref-name>jms/customQueue</resource-env-ref-name>
            <resource-env-ref-type>javax.jms.Queue</resource-env-ref-type>
         </resource-env-ref>

      </session>
```

I added following configuration to `standalone-full.xml` `urn:jboss:domain:messaging-activemq:13.0`:

```xml
  <connection-factory name="customQueueFactory" entries="java:/jms/customQueueFactory" connectors="in-vm"/>
  <jms-queue name="customQueue" entries="java:/jms/customQueue"/>
```

But when I start jboss the jms resources cannot get resolved:

```
02:26:30,651 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "app.ear")]) - failure description: {
    "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => [
        "jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.resources.jms.customQueueFactory",
        "jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.resources.jms.customQueue"
    ],
    "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => [
        "jboss.naming.context.java.comp.app.app-mdb.Sender.env.jms.customQueueFactory is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.resources.jms.customQueueFactory]",
        "jboss.naming.context.java.comp.app.app-mdb.Sender.env.jms.customQueue is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.resources.jms.customQueue]"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Default lookup prefix for jboss-eap 7.4 is `java:jboss/resources`. So in order to get this to work the exported names need to be adjusted accordingly:

```xml
  <connection-factory name="customQueueFactory" entries="java:jboss/resources/jms/customQueueFactory" connectors="in-vm"/>
  <jms-queue name="customQueue" entries="java:jboss/resources/jms/customQueue"/>
```